# How to delegate message from vaadin client class to server class?

Tags: java, vaadin

I am using server RPC  for this delegation but nothing is fired.

Step 1 - **Create server rpc**:

```
public interface UploadServerRpc extends ServerRpc {
    public void clicked(String buttonName);
}
```

Step 2 - **Create connector class**:

```
public class UploadComponentConnector extends UploadConnector {
    UploadServerRpc rpc = RpcProxy.create(UploadServerRpc.class, this);
            public UploadComponentConnector() {
                if(getWidget().isSubClick()) {
                 rpc.clicked(getWidget().getNotificationName());
                }
    }
}
```

Step 3 - **Server side class**:

```
public class UploadComponent extends Upload {
    private UploadServerRpc srpc = new UploadServerRpc() {
            @Override
            public void clicked(String name) {
                Notification notification = new Notification(name);
                UI.getCurrent().getPage().showNotification(notification);
            }
    };
    public UploadComponent() {    
        registerRpc(srpc);
    }
}
```

*Note : inside VUpload class hanling some restriction itsworking but cannot delegate notification messsage*

Nothing happened ....when i clicked vaadin Upload button .

Comment: [Are you missing a `@Connect`](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/gwt.rpc.html#gwt.rpc.server-side)?

Comment: I have not missed @connect but its not working

Comment: Are you sure you want to call the RPC in the constructor of the connector? It looks wrong

Comment: @Artur signell 
Yes i am sure, if you have any doubt please refer the link https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/gwt.rpc.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define a handler on widget side to handle the click event. Putting your logic in the Connector's constructor is not correct. Use below code for connector instead (hope to help you):

```
public class UploadComponentConnector extends UploadConnector {
    UploadServerRpc rpc = RpcProxy.create(UploadServerRpc.class, this);
    public UploadComponentConnector() {
        getWidget().addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                rpc.clicked(getWidget().getNotificationName());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: if you find this helpful, please check it as answer.